# Co-operation of servlets and async CompletableFuture operations?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, asynchronous, java-8

We have web API where we are basically using plain servlets as request handlers. The request handlers are mainly simple wrappers for *one or more* async method calls of some module that we are using. Fortunately, we are using java8, so module async methods returns promises, i.e. `CompletableFuture`.

In other words, in sudo diagram:

```
request -> servlet -> module.asyncFoo().thenAsyncBar();
```

Since this is an API, request must return a (json) response.

What bothers me here is that we have two thread pools - or thread managers:

- servlet container (jetty in our case) manages requests
- module, manages async calls.

At the moment, we are not using the module in async way, since we do call futures `get()` inside the request handler (i.e. servlet) to prepare the response.

Is it possible somehow to 'reuse' the existing containers thread pool executor, so we can *continue* the execution of the modules within the same thread manager? Our module allows us to set `Executor` instead of `ForkJoinPool`.

In other words: is there a *performant* java HTTP server that is ready for java8? It doesn't have to be servlet container, since all I need it request handling.

And of course, would all this make sense and would it make any difference for performances? I would say yes, since number of available working threads would double.

Comment: You are right about "call futures in servlet, doesnt make this all async" and nice question by the way. But if you do your servlet answers asynchronously, still your server will be waiting for a response. I think best practice will be web sockets or something like web push. When the response ready, it will be pushed.